# WCF REST, PerCall, Castle.Core interceptor performance issue

Tags: wcf, rest, service, intercept

I have n-tier application where the "WCF REST Service Application" is in the top. For performance consideration, the context mode is PerCall such as the following

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

I also have a Intercept (Castle.Core) for logging purposes in the same way like this:

- [Interceptors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Interceptors&NS=Windsor)
- [Logging the AOP way](http://ayende.com/blog/3474/logging-the-aop-way)

The implementaion:

```
public static readonly ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

public static T Create<T>(object target, ILog log)
{
    return (T)generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(T), target, new LoggingInterceptor(log));
}

private class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
        ...
}
```

The interceptor:

```
IUserHandler handler = ObjectFactory.Create<IUserHandler>(new UserHandler(), log);

handler.GetUsers();
```

By using interceptor each method calls have about 0,3 additional seconds which is quite a lot. Why is it?! Is there another way to get interceptor working without such huge performance overhead?!

Comment: Is it the proxy adding the time or the logging code?  Have you timed it with with empty logging advice?

Comment: I also turned the logging off and check the preformance, but there was very minimal change (in my case: <log4net threshold="Off"/>). When I changed the code from normal object creation to [ObjectFactory.Create] I got this performance descreasing.